# Java (Eclipse) - How can I get an .exe file and keep a .xml file for editing purposes

Tags: java, xml, eclipse

I finished coding my program. Now I wanna share it with the world for everyones favour. My program needs to read data out of a .xml file, which should stay editable - I want the user to create own settings.

I already exported my project to an executable JAR File. The .xml file was part of the src folder and is inside the JAR.

Now I wanna convert the executable JAR into an .exe file. But I want to keep that .xml file, so the user can still make changes. If I use a tool like Launch4j, it just creates an .exe file, that barely works.

I hope for helpful answers.

Regards,
SLyzer

Answer (score 0):

One option is to turn your project into a [gradle](https://gradle.org) project that uses the [application plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html).

The application plugin will let you build a zip file containing a bin directory with a Windows bat and UNIX shell scripts that are used to launch the application.  The zip file also contains your JAR file and all the JAR file dependencies for your application, so your application is self-contained in the zip file.  You can also configure other data files to be copied into the zip file such as your XML configuration file.

The Eclipse Buildship plugin provides excellent integration of gradle and eclipse.